# In MATLAB can I convert a java boolean to a MATLAB logical?

Tags: java, mysql, matlab, boolean

In MATLAB I'm using a couple of java routines I've written to interface with a MyQSL database. One routine returns a boolean value

```
result  <1x1 java.lang.Boolean>
>> result 
result =
true
```

When I then use it in a conditional statement I get an error message.

```
>> if result,
disp('result is true')
end
??? Conversion to logical from java.lang.Boolean is not possible.
```

Is there a way to use the java boolean class as a MATLAB logical type? Or do I have to resort to returning integer values from my java routines?

Comment: If this is a Java routine you wrote, are you returning java.lang.Boolean or the primitive boolean? If you return primitves, they'll automatically convert to Matlab types. The boxed value objects won't. If you get to returning arrays, double[] and Double[] have performance impacts: primitives are faster.

Comment: I'm still a java novice so I'm not too sure. In the routine I declare 'boolean row = false;' and then at the end 'return row;'. Now when this gets back to MATLAB it's identified it a java.lang.Boolean . Are you saying this is different to the primitive boolean type? Yes I've noticed that returning int and double types that these automatically get converted to native MATLAB float type. It's just the boolean type that doesn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Example:

```
b = java.lang.Boolean(true);

if b.booleanValue
    disp('val is true')
else
    disp('val is false')
end
```

And to make sure:

```
>> v = b.booleanValue;
>> whos v
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class      Attributes

  v         1x1                 1  logical
```